# Espresso - Activity is getting closed after every test Method. Is there way we can`t stop closing activity and running other test Methods

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-espresso

spresso - Activity is getting closed after every test Method. Is there way we can`t stop closing activity and running other test Methods

Comment: No, why do you need to keep same activity open?

Comment: If the state of the application isn't changing, you could check multiple different things in the application (multiple test cases) without needing to go thru the entire setup process for each individual test.  It really sucks if there is no way to do this in Espresso as it will increase the runtime of the tests a lot unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you mean, you may do one of these solutions:

- Write down one big test to test all desired views without any
  interruption:

  ```
  @Test
  public void checkIfMainActivityViewsAreProperlyDisplayed() {

      //Check if activity name is visible on Toolbar
      onView(withText(R.string.action_main)).check(matches(withParent(withId(R.id.toolbar))));

      //Check if ListView is visible at least 50 percent 
      onView(withId(R.id.mListView)).check(matches(isDisplayingAtLeast(50)));

      //Check if order Checkbox is checked. Perform check.
      onView(withId(R.id.mCheckBox))
              .check(matches(isNotChecked()))
              .perform(ViewActions.click())
              .check(matches(isChecked()));
  }
  ```

Use comments to make your code more clear for others

- Write down tests suite and add it to main method like below:

  ```
   private void checkifActivityNameIsVisibleOnToolbar() {
        onView(withText(R.string.action_main)).check(matches(withParent(withId(R.id.toolbar))));
   }

   private void checkifListViewIsVisibleAtLeastFiftyPercent() {
        onView(withId(R.id.mListView)).check(matches(isDisplayingAtLeast(50)));
   }

   private void performClickOnOrderCheckBoxToFindIfStateChanged() {
      onView(withId(R.id.mOrder))
          .check(matches(isNotChecked()))
          .perform(ViewActions.click())
          .check(matches(isChecked()));
   }

  @Test
  public void checkIfMainActivityViewsAreProperlyDisplayed() throws InterruptedException {
        checkifActivityNameIsVisibleOnToolbar();
        checkifListViewIsVisibleAtLeastFiftyPercent();
        performClickOnOrderCheckBoxToFindIfStateChanged();
  }
  ```

It might be easier to maintain the test code then the previous one.

Hope it will help

Comment: Good as as workaround, but can't test individual cases this way. So is Espresso that bad we have to write individual test case classes if we want activity to be relaunched? Also I don't then understand how this test case has two test methods, if activity closes after each one: https://github.com/designatednerd/Wino/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/designatednerd/wino/ui/WineTastingDetailUITests.java